# Creating new date object which includes timezone identifier

Tags: javascript, facebook, iso

I am querying event start times from Facebook's API. Most often, they return the string like the following:

```
2014-04-02T20:00:00-0600
```

But sometimes, it is returned like:

```
2014-04-19
```

When I try to create a new date object, it does not work with the timezone identifier.

However, both of these work:

```
var d = new Date('2014-04-02T20:00:00')
```

or

```
var d = new Date('2014-04-19')
```

But I need this to work:

```
var d = new Date('2014-04-02T20:00:00-0600')
// returns Invalid Date
```

I'm trying to avoid parsing each start_time string to see if I need to remove the timezone identifier since I am working with hundreds of events.

Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying, or do I actually need to remove the timezone identifier for each date that has it?

Comment: Does this help - http://engineering.nulogy.com/posts/dealing-with-timezones-in-javascript/?

Comment: You will need to "manually" parse the string. It's not hard, you only have to write the code once. But you do need to say excatly what you want to do. Do you want to convert say `2014-04-02T20:00:00-0600` to the local time of a user, or to present it in a specific timezone (e.g. UTC)?

Comment: Have you tried using timestamptz class?

Comment: @jp310 Yes, that is some helpful information. I was trying to avoid using the moment.js libraries. But I will give it a consideration.

Comment: @RobG Yes, I know it is not difficult. That is a good insight as to if I want to do anything with the offset in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse an ISO 8601 string with offset using the following. If the string has no offset, it is assumed to be Z (i.e. UTC per [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)):

```
/* Parse an ISO string with an offset
**   e.g. '2014-04-02T20:00:00-0600'
**        '2014-04-02T20:00:00Z'
**
** Allows decimal seconds if supplied
**   e.g. '2014-04-02T20:00:00.123-0600'
**
** If no offset is supplied (or it's Z), treat as UTC (per ECMA-262)
** If date only, e.g. '2014-04-02', treat as UTC date (per ECMA-262)
*/
function parseISOString(s) {
  var t = s.split(/\D+/g);
  var hasOffset = /\d{2}[-+]\d{4}$/.test(s);

  // Whether decimal seconds are present changes the offset field and ms value
  var hasDecimalSeconds = /T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+/i.test(s);
  var offset = hasDecimalSeconds? t[7] : t[6];
  var ms = hasDecimalSeconds? t[6] : 0;
  var offMin, offSign, min;

  // If there's an offset, apply it to minutes to get a UTC time value
  if (hasOffset) {
    offMin = 60 * offset / 100 + offset % 100;
    offSign = /-\d{4}$/.test(s)? -1 : 1;
  }
  min = hasOffset? +t[4] - offMin * offSign : (t[4] || 0);

  // Return a date object based on UTC values
  return new Date(Date.UTC(t[0], --t[1], t[2], t[3]||0, min, t[5]||0, ms));
}

// Tests
console.log(parseISOString('2014-04-02T20:00:00-0600').toISOString());    // 2014-04-03T02:00:00.000Z
console.log(parseISOString('2014-04-02T20:00:00Z').toISOString());        // 2014-04-02T20:00:00.000Z
console.log(parseISOString('2014-04-02T20:00:00').toISOString());         // 2014-04-02T20:00:00.000Z
console.log(parseISOString('2014-04-02T20:00:00.123-0600').toISOString());// 2014-04-03T02:00:00.123Z
console.log(parseISOString('2014-04-02T20:00:00.123').toISOString());     // 2014-04-02T20:00:00.123Z
console.log(parseISOString('2014-04-02').toISOString());                  // 2014-04-02T00:00:00.000Z
```

Note that if this will create a date object with an offset for the timezone of the host environment based on system settings. The timevalue of the Date will be the equivalent UTC time for the supplied timestamp (in this case, '2014-04-03T02:00:00Z'). You can confirm that using the *toISOString* method (requires IE9 or higher, or other modern browser).

#### Edit

Note that you can't set the timezone offset of a Date object. They have a time value that represents a UTC moment in time, and a timezone offset that is based on system settings. You can read "local" date and time values using standard Date methods like *getFullYear* and *getHours*, or UTC values if UTC methods are used (e.g. *getUTCFullYear*, *getUTCHours*).

#### Edit 2

Allowed for date only format (treats it as UTC).

Comment: I like where this is going. However, as stated in the question, sometimes the start_time for an event is formatted like: `2014-04-19` which in this case, will fail. I suppose though I could use this for when I come across the start_time with identifier.

Comment: I've added support for date only format, it's treated as UTC. Is that what you need? Pretty easy to treat it as a local date.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your time. Much better doing this than including a library.